# Regular Expressions - Repeating Pattern

Tags: c#, regex, regular-language

I just cannot seem to get it.... I have a string of text that I need to extract a repeating pattern from but I can only get a small part of it, or I get a single match of the whole string...

The string is a concatenation of "markers" plus "content" and I need to extract each marker, and its content.

```
string s = "T:     2  YE             I:      4  YE";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, "(?'marker'(T|I)):(?'content'.+)");
while (m.Success)
{
    string Marker = m.Groups["marker"].value; // (T: or I:)
    string Content = m.Groups["content"].value; // (2 YE or 4 YE)
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

I've tried both ".+" and ".+?" for max/min capture but I either get 2 matches that have markers but no content, or one match with WHOLE input string.

Any pointers please :)

Comment: Can T or I be part of content?

Comment: Opps... forgot the "nextmatch()"

Comment: They will never be in the content... however, I don't mind them being extracted as a part of the "content" match group (instead or the marker group(

Comment: T or I may exist in the content... but not "T:" or "I:".... to further complicate matters, I only posted a simple version... other markers are "ST:" and "SI:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?'marker'(T|I)):(?'content'.+)
```

Won't work because `.+` will consume the entire rest of the line (it's matches greedily, and there's nothing preventing it consuming the rest of the line).

```
(?'marker'(T|I)):(?'content'.+?)
```

The `.+?` will only consume a single character and then stop, since it reluctantly matches.

You'll need to be able to specify when "content" ends.  I really don't understand the format you've provided well enough to be sure I know the correct way to do this, but assuming that any number of capital letter followed by a colon (like "T:", "ST:", or "ORANGUTANS:") qualify as a marker, this should work:

```
([A-Z]+:)(((?![A-Z]+:).)+)
```

Which uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to recognize where the next marker begins.  The first and second capturing groups should capture the marker and content respectively.

I'm not so familiar with the syntax your using to name the capturing groups, but I believe this should work:

```
(?'marker'[A-Z]+:)(?'content'((?![A-Z]+:).)+)
```

Comment: Awesome Regex and nice explanation - Negative Lookahead always still catches me!! +1!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex("(T:|I:)").Split(s);
```